# hyperlink problem in my outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Whenever I am typing an hyperlink on outllok in a message body, outllok transform it automatically to a text like this one:
 {hyperlink: www.google.com}

but when I am sending it, it sends it as a normal hyperlink

how can I rmeove this auto formattating by outlook?

thanks

Comment: Hyperlink Problems? In *your* Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have Word as the email editor and configured it to show Field Codes. To disable it:

Outlook/Word 2003 and previous:

While composing choose Tools > Options > Tab View > section Show and uncheck the option “Field codes”.

Outlook/Word 2007:

Press the Office logo in the left upper corner > Editor Options > Advanced > section “Display e-mail content” and uncheck the option “Show field codes instead of their values”.